# How to retrieve all fasta records that contain any of a list of strings in the header

Tags: python, string, search, biopython, fasta

I want a script that can extract all fasta records from a file which contain any of a list of strings in the header.

So if I had a list in one file like this:

```
2.A.1.13.5
3.A.1.208.23
```

And a fasta file like this:

```
>gnl|TC-DB|O60645|1.F.2.1.2 Exocyst complex component 3 OS=Homo sapiens GN=EXOC3 PE=1 SV=2
MQCEDSTSFFTMKETDREAVATAVQRVAGMLQRPDQLDKVEQYRRREARKKASVEARLKA
>gnl|TC-DB|O60669|2.A.1.13.5 Monocarboxylate transporter 2 - Homo sapiens (Human).
MPPMPSAPPVHPPPDGGWGWIVVGAAFISIGFSYAFPKAVTVFFKEIQQIFHTTYSEIAW
>gnl|TC-DB|O60683|3.A.20.1.1 Peroxisome biogenesis factor 10 OS=Homo sapiens GN=PEX10 PE=1 SV=1
MAPAAASPPEVIRAAQKDEYYRGGLRSAAGGALHSLAGARKWLEWRKEVELLSDVAYFGL
>gnl|TC-DB|O60684|1.I.1.1.3 Importin subunit alpha-7 OS=Homo sapiens GN=KPNA6 PE=1 SV=1
METMASPGKDNYRMKSYKNNALNPEEMRRRREEEGIQLRKQKREQQLFKRRNVELINEEA
>gnl|TC-DB|O60706|3.A.1.208.23 ATP-binding cassette sub-family C member 9 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ABCC9 PE=1 SV=2
MSLSFCGNNISSYNINDGVLQNSCFVDALNLVPHVFLLFITFPILFIGWGSQSSKVQIHH
>gnl|TC-DB|O60721|3.A.1.208.23 Sodium/potassium/calcium exchanger 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=SLC24A1 PE=1 SV=1
MGKLIRMGPQERWLLRTKRLHWSRLLFLLGMLIIGSTYQHLRRPRGLSSLWAAVSSHQPI
>gnl|TC-DB|O60779|2.A.1.13.5 Thiamine transporter 1 (THTR-1) (ThTr1) (Thiamine carrier 1) (TC1) - Homo sapiens (Human).
MDVPGPVSRRAAAAAATVLLRTARVRRECWFLPTALLCAYGFFASLRPSEPFLTPYLLGP
```

Then the script would print the 2nd, 5th, 6th and 7th records, like so:

```
>gnl|TC-DB|O60669|2.A.1.13.5 Monocarboxylate transporter 2 - Homo sapiens (Human).
MPPMPSAPPVHPPPDGGWGWIVVGAAFISIGFSYAFPKAVTVFFKEIQQIFHTTYSEIAW
>gnl|TC-DB|O60706|3.A.1.208.23 ATP-binding cassette sub-family C member 9 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ABCC9 PE=1 SV=2
MSLSFCGNNISSYNINDGVLQNSCFVDALNLVPHVFLLFITFPILFIGWGSQSSKVQIHH
>gnl|TC-DB|O60721|3.A.1.208.23 Sodium/potassium/calcium exchanger 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=SLC24A1 PE=1 SV=1
MGKLIRMGPQERWLLRTKRLHWSRLLFLLGMLIIGSTYQHLRRPRGLSSLWAAVSSHQPI
>gnl|TC-DB|O60779|2.A.1.13.5 Thiamine transporter 1 (THTR-1) (ThTr1) (Thiamine carrier 1) (TC1) - Homo sapiens (Human).
MDVPGPVSRRAAAAAATVLLRTARVRRECWFLPTALLCAYGFFASLRPSEPFLTPYLLGP
```

Here's the kind of approach I was taking but I could be miles off as not really sure what I'm doing. I've been told BioPython is good for handling fasta format files but still trying to get to grasps with it.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys

headers = []

search_list = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in search_list:
    headers.append(line.rstrip())
search_list.close()

print search_list

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(sys.argv[2], "fasta"):
    #print seq_record
    for a in headers:
        head = str(a)
        if head in seq_record:
            print seq_record
```

Cheers in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has almost everything. You just need to check if the header is in the `description`, then print the [SeqRecord](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) elements and you are done.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys

headers = list()

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as search_list:
    for line in search_list:
        headers.append(line.rstrip())

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(sys.argv[2], "fasta"):
    for head in headers:
        if head in seq_record.description:
            print(seq_record.format('fasta'))
            break
```

Small note: I added a `break` statement after the first found element, in case two headers are found it would print it twice.

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
list_items = '|'.join(list(open('list.txt').read().split('\n')))

with open('fasta.txt') as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        if re.search(list_items, line ):
            print line
```

Output :

> gnl|TC-DB|O60669|2.A.1.13.5 Monocarboxylate transporter 2 - Homo sapiens (Human).
>   gnl|TC-DB|O60706|3.A.1.208.23 ATP-binding cassette sub-family C member 9 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ABCC9 PE=1 SV=2
>   gnl|TC-DB|O60721|3.A.1.208.23 Sodium/potassium/calcium exchanger 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=SLC24A1 PE=1 SV=1
>   gnl|TC-DB|O60779|2.A.1.13.5 Thiamine transporter 1 (THTR-1) (ThTr1) (Thiamine carrier 1) (TC1) - Homo sapiens (Human).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry that isn't the kind of output I wanted. I've edited my original question to include the sort of output I want so hopefully that's more descriptive.